# OpenGL - Perspective Issue

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I just want to create a perspective where the eye of the camera would be, at, say: (2, 2, -2), looking right at the origin. I'm trying to use a combination of `gluLookAt()` and `glFrustum()`, but for some reason, though it is rendering, my objects look very distorted:

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 500.0);

... 

gluLookAt (-2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Here is a screenshot. The left side defines a profile curve to be swept around the y-axis. It should be a cylinder in the perspective view, but it's... warped.

[image]

**EDIT 2**: Also, those axis in the perspective view are set up as followed, which I know isn't correct:

```
// draw the axis
   glBegin(GL_LINES);
     // x
     glVertex3f(500.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glVertex3f(-500.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     // y
     glVertex3f(0.0, -500.0, 0.0);
     glVertex3f(0.0, 500.0, 0.0);
     // z
     glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -500.0);
     glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 500.0);

   glEnd();
```

**EDIT 3**: Also, none of the vertices of that shape have an x, y, or z value greater than 1.0..

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you're getting.

Comment: @ChrisF: I've posted a screenshot.

Comment: It looks like you're just a little too close to the object. Move the camera further away.

Comment: @ChrisF: As per my edit, my maximum vertex range is only up to (1,1,1), so I don't think getting further away helps. I tried, but it made it really small.

Comment: Running out of ideas now. What's the field of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

I don't thing you're doing wrong anything. The kind of view you want to have in your left pane is usually done using a *orthographic* projection. The distortion you see is just a perspective distortion; you're not looking perpendicular onto the curve (the curve lies in the XY plane, and you're looking at the XY plane from some angle).

#### Side note:

The projection matrix only defines the "*lens*" of OpenGL. It must not be used to place the "camera". Any eyepoint positioning (the *view*) is defined as part of the modelview transformation. Thus `gluLookAt` is meant to be used on the modelview matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Your frustum is set up as if the screen is square. If your screen isn't square this will distort the objects badly.

Also, if the objects are close to your camera, the near and far distances can affect the image.

And one more thing, your up axis in gluLookAt is pointing down.

Posting a screenshot would help identify the problem.

Comment: Your problem is that your up axis is wrong. Switch your gluLookAt to (-2,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)

Comment: It looks the way it does because you are actually looking at the object from underneath in your screenshot.